# Does ArrayList represent an Object Pool Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, objectpool

I want to know if `ArrayList` represent an Object Pool Pattern. It has an array of `Object` inside. And all objects of `ArrayList` can frequently be reused.

Comment: You can use a `List` to implement a pool so that it will be the backing storage in you `ObjectPool` class, but the `List` itself definitely is not an implementation of the Object pool pattern.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question...

Comment: If anything, a Queue would make a better base for implementing a pool.

Comment: @Arkadiy, please, explain why.

Comment: offer() and poll() I think are closer to object pool semantics than add() and remove(0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` can be a pool container, but it isn't an object pool itself. It needs some algorithmic support to implement caching.
If you, for example, keep track of the head and the tail of the array instead of adding/removing objects to/from the array as it should be, you'll get some kind of manual memory management. Your objects won't be deleted and will probably be reused. Thereat you'll have the right to say that your program uses [The object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).